# node js -how to delete particular _id data from array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

this is my delete function route.js

```
router.delete("/qus/:id/answers/:answersId", function(req, res) {
        Forum.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, {
                $pull: {
                    "answers" : { "answers._id": req.body.answersId }
                }
            }, { safe: true, multi: true },
            function(err,result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.json({msg:"somethong went wrong"})
                }
                else {
                   res.json({msg:"success"});
                  // res.redirect("/qus/" + foundAnimal._id + "/answers");
                }
            });
    });
```

my api look like

```
{
  "success": true,
  "forums": [
    {
      "createdAt": "2018-11-26T05:26:37.829Z",
      "likes": 0,
      "likedBy": [],
      "dislikes": 0,
      "dislikedBy": [],
      "_id": "5bfb84776cd9ea0ebc3db87b",
      "title": "how to apply visa",
      "body": "student visa requirement
      "qus_comments": [],
      "answers": [
        {
          "createdAt": "2018-11-26T06:59:21.840Z",
          "likesAnswer": 0,
          "likedAnswerBy": [],
          "dislikesAnswer": 0,
          "dislikedAnswerBy": [],
          "_id": "5bfb99eb21a1911650eba0d9",
          "content": "asdfghjk",
        },
        {
          "createdAt": "2018-11-26T06:59:21.840Z",
          "likesAnswer": 0,
          "likedAnswerBy": [],
          "dislikesAnswer": 0,
          "dislikedAnswerBy": [],
          "_id": "5bfb99f321a1911650eba0da",
          "content": "refersadfghj",
        }
      ],
      "__v": 13
    }
  ]
}
```

my delete function working , this function delete whole answers array, but i want delete any particular id in this answers array. please help me. i don't know , how to implement this one . if anyone know please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `answers._id` directly when you are using `$pull` for the given data structure you have:

```js
Forum.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, {
  $pull: {"answers._id": req.body.answersId}
 },{ safe: true, multi: true },
 function(err,result) {
  if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.json({msg:"somethong went wrong"})
  }
  else {
     res.json({msg:"success"});
    // res.redirect("/qus/" + foundAnimal._id + "/answers");
 }
});
```

In some cases, may be due to difference in mongodb version, below works:

```
Forum.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, {
  $pull: {"answers" : {"_id": req.body.answersId} }
});
```

Comment: if i use this '$pull: {"answers" : {"_id": req.body.answersId} }' delete function not working

Comment: @indu ECE - And you shouldn't be using option **multi** with findOneAndUpdate.

Comment: @Ankit Agarwal i didn't get any error, i get success msg ,but that id not delete in api

Comment: What about database, is it removed there? @induECE

Comment: @ Ankit Agarwal , my code ,router.delete("/qus/:id/answers/:answersId", function(req, res) {
        Forum.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, {
                $pull:{"answers" : {"_id": req.body.answersId} }
            }, { safe: true},
            function(err,result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.json({msg:"somethong went wrong"})
                }
                else {
                   res.json({msg:"success"});
                }
            });
    });

Comment: @induECE it might be the case that there are no records with ` _id: req.params.id ` or even `"_id": req.body.answersId`

Comment: @induECE was that the case? :-)

Comment: @Ankit Agarwal yes,  i used "_id": req.params.answersId ,it working properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184265/discussion-between-ankit-agarwal-and-indu-ece).